# adding php string to some javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I'm trying to add a php string to some javascript:

```
document.getElementById("button").value = mygetrequest.responseText;
```

basically there are a load of buttons on one page.

So i need to add a value at the end of button. 

Basically the ID of each row so button`<? echo $row['ID']; ?>` but i'm not too sure how i would do this in javascript.

Any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ocument.getElementById("button").value = mygetrequest.responseText + "<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>";
```

Comment: @suresh atta if you are satisfied with this answer click accept answer button (the tick) =)